# Python: post files using httplib2

Tags: python, http-post, httplib2

Trying to post files of few MB in size. I made it working using python-requests package with multiform data, but now I need to add 2 way SSL support and unfortunately the python-requests version 0.8.2-1 doesn't have the support for 2 way SS. We are on ubuntu 12.04 and 0.8.2-1 is the latest version available for 12.04.

Can this be done using httplib2? As I am using httplib2 for 2 way SSL in other applications so would like to use the same common httplib2 library for all http requests.

Comment: Don't use distribution supported python packages. Use upstream packages from PyPi. pip ftw. Seriously don't.

Comment: @JamesMills: Unfortunately I cannot diverge getting packages from distribution. But is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do using httplib2?

Comment: There probably is; since requests itself uses httplib; However I *have* to ask; Why? Tying your deployments to the distribution and the distribution packages is a silly idea.

Comment: @JamesMills: Actually the reason is other modules in our solution use a common library which uses httplib2 for all http POST/GET. Team wants to use that common-lib and doesn't want to add new python-requests package if it's not part of 12.04 distribution and hence stuck with finding an alternative to requests. I was reading about python-poster to do multipart/form kind of thing will httplib2 (0.7.2-1ubuntu2.1) be able to work with multipart_encode I can see urrlib2 can but not sure about httplib2. Thanks!